# How to fix KIVY default window on app appearing thin on launch... almost without width?

Tags: python, kivy

All of the projects I opened on Kivy open up with a really long but thin window... I have no idea why or how I this happened. Could someone please help me fix this?

Here is a screen shot! Thank you so much
-https://drive.google.com/file/d/17PeHfFJBkMPI-eW4PbO8qzwG2W2IM1hn/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You may set the width and height before opening your window:

```py
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.0')

from kivy.config import Config

# Ensure window is going to be 800x400
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '400')
```

Alternatively, you can set the window size after creating it with its size attribute, which is a (width, height) tuple:

```py
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (800, 400)
```

You can find more configuration options here: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.config.html

Comment: Thank you Ruben! I appreciate your answer. I am aware of the settings I can apply to change my window size... I'm perplexed though with why my initial default window size is now just the height with no width. Were you able to see my screen shot, it's very weird and all my kivy projects are opening up like that. (the ones where I did not specifically set a window.size)

Comment: Yes I saw the screenshot. Any chance you have a very low width set in your configuration file, usually at `~/.kivy/config.ini`? Otherwise I wouldn't know, but you can apply a band-aid on the issue by setting a minimum width in your window with `Window.minimum_width = NUM_PIXELS`.

Comment: I've never touched this file I wonder if I ran some other install that would trigger this... Here are my settings:

[graphics]
display = -1
fullscreen = 0
height = 600
left = 0
maxfps = 60
multisamples = 2
position = auto
rotation = 0
show_cursor = 1
top = 0
width = 100
resizable = 1
borderless = 0
window_state = visible
minimum_width = 0
minimum_height = 0
min_state_time = .035
allow_screensaver = 1
shaped = 0

Comment: Ha! Well you were right. I switched 'width' to 600 and it's "fixed"... man I wish I knew what I did to cause that! Either way thank you so much man!! :)

Comment: Well you have width set to 100 and height set to 600 so that would explain it. You can manually change that to reasonable values. As to what caused your issue, some Kivy program may have saved these values permanently (this can be done by doing `Config.write` after `Config.set`).